# Setting up Zhuyin input keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, microsoft-word, chinese

I type up a lot of Chinese characters, and am quite used to typing in Pinyin.

However, I'd like to teach my students, who were initially taught using Zhuyin, to use Pinyin, since Pinyin usage is far more widespread and ubiquitous in today's world.

However, using Window's native input is inconvenient: I have to place a space after every character, and I have to copy-paste all the tones. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Computer Zhuyin]

But I'd like it to look like this:

[image: Modified Zhuyin]

where the tone/diacritic is placed between the last two characters, and the characters are stacked (since that's the way my students have learned it).

There's an excellent project named [Pinyinput](http://pinyinput.sourceforge.net/) which does this for Pinyin; is there something similar, or am I stuck typing Zhuyin out like I currently am?